# C++. Only authorized in AD users should be able to launch the program

Tags: c++, active-directory

I am going to write a tool, which authorizes on AD server, sends some data(objectID for example) to the backend server. Backend checks this data. If the client has enough rights, backend will send some data back to the client.

It doesn't look secure for me, to send an objectID or something like this, because it is too easy to still it and use again.

How can i make it more secure? Is it possible to send some session id to the backend and on the backend side verify the user, using this id, his ip and something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't authorize on the client. Anyone can examine the protocol and hack it. You send your request and credentials securely to the server which does the AD authentication. It then creates a session for which auth is approved.

Comment: Correct, in order to perform a secure authentication, you need to establish a secure channel (SSL or TLS), transmit credentials in secure manner and get a session token. Alternatively, your server may have a method to return anonymous session token with which you encrypt credentials, send them to the server and get final session key - although that is duplicate work that can be performed at lower layer.